# Sass remove a map key inside a mixin

Tags: sass

Map:

```
$map-breakpoints: (
  xs: (
    min-width: 0,
    max-width: 480px
  ),
  sm: (
    min-width: 481px,
    max-width: 750px
  ),
  md: (
    min-width: 751px,
    max-width: 1170px
  )
) !default;
```

Mixin:

```
@mixin example($map: $map-breakpoints) {
  // i want remove map key `md`, i dont need map key `md` in this mixin
}
```

How can remove a map key inside a mixin like above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have a look at the [Sass functions](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#map-functions) on maps. There exists a `map-remove` function which returns a new list without the passed keys. Ex:

```
map-remove($map-breakpoints, md, sm) // md, sm are keys of the map
```

The example will remove both the md and the sm keys (with their values) from the resulting map.

Comment: Awesome, this answer working,  just want know more info, can it be remove `except` some key, like remove all key except `md` something like that? thanks so much.

Comment: Removing everything except one element, is a bit more tricky. I would say that it would be easier (and cleaner) to just pick the element you want to use out of the map directly using: `map-get($my-map, wanted-element)`

Comment: Just tried to use map-remove with a list in second argument and see it's not working https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/f543bb4b54b558bd9b77ebd5c60960c6

Comment: @ Даниил Пронин you're passing the to-be-removed keys wrongly. They should be passed as regular arguments: `map-remove($my-map, key1, key2, key3)`